# set unset variable, scope CMD Script Windows, routines

Tags: variables, batch-file, scope, subroutine

I want to know how solve this:

```
rem declaring variable
set "vara="
echo vara:%vara% bef
call :myroutine
echo vara:%vara% aft

:routine
rem ...
rem assing value to variable vara
set "vara=34"
echo vara was assigned...
rem ....
echo vara:%vara%
exit /b
```

Now I have this later:

```
vara: bef
vara was assigned
vara:34
vara: aft
```

I need to use the value after of routine, like this...

```
vara: bef
vara was assigned
vara:34
vara:34 aft
```

vara:**34** aft
How to do it?

Answer (score 1):

That's what happens already, assuming you call the correct label.  (:myroutine != :routine).  There are a couple of other minor issues with your script (missing `goto :EOF` before `:routine`, and doing `@echo off` and `setlocal`).  Here it is fixed:

```
@echo off
setlocal
rem declaring variable
set "vara="
echo vara:%vara% bef
call :routine
echo vara:%vara% aft

set "vara="
goto :EOF

:routine
rem ...
rem assing value to variable vara
set "vara=34"
echo vara was assigned...
rem ....
echo vara:%vara%
exit /b
```

For more information about calling subroutines / functions, see [this page](http://www.dostips.com/DtTutoFunctions.php), paying special attentions to the sections regarding different methods of returning values.  What you're describing in your question already works like you want unless you `setlocal` within your `:routine`.

Comment: is there difference using goto :EOF exit /b?
.                  . what advantage i have using setlocal?

Comment: For this script, there's no difference between `goto :EOF` and `exit /b`.  The only real difference between the two is that `exit /b` allows you to set `%ERRORLEVEL%` to a non-zero value if you wish.  See [this page](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/exit.php) for more information.  Using `setlocal` prevents your script from junking up your operating environment with variables that are only relevant to the script.  Without `setlocal`, `%vara%` will remain defined after the script exits -- or it would without the `set "vara="` line, anyway.  This is usually unwelcome unless done intentionally.